# EXTJS 6.7 - class properties not cleared on destroy

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I've created a fiddle just to simulate my problem with class property not being reset on window destroy.
How to test:
Open fiddle, press OPEN button, ADD 3 panels, close ext window, press OPEN button again, and add a some more panels.
Panel numbers represent the length of the _panels array property in window.
Now to the problem.
As you can see panel NUMBER when adding new panels is not reset. So if you add 3 panels and close the window, reopen the window panels count shows 3 and then 4 and then 5 instead of 0 1 2 ...
My question is, why?

[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38qo)

Kind regards

Armando

**EDIT** : so one can see the solution
I ended fixing my application to work like this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38s9). I moved properties to constructor.

```
constructor: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {     
        width: 800,      
        height: 600, 
        layout: 'vbox', 
        _panels : []
    }); 
    this.callParent(arguments); 
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define

```js
Ext.define('TestWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    _panel: []
});
```

The `TestWindow` definition class gets empty array property (no-primitive datatype). When you create an instance by `var win = Ext.create('TestWindow')`, the instance gets that property. However, when you set:

```js
   onDestroy: function() {
      this._panels = [];
    },
```

it sets empty array to property `_panels` of the instance `win`, not on the definition class `TestWindow`; `TestWindow` keeps the existing mutated `_panel`. And when next time you create new instance, it gets same `_panel` from class definition.

I understand you did it for demo purpose to show the problem. However, I prefer to let framework do all heavy-lifting (create and destroy etc):

```js
Ext.define('TestWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    width: 800,
    height: 600,

    defaultListenerScope: true,
    layout: 'vbox',

    initComponent: function() {
        this._panels = [];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    addPanel: function() {
        console.log(this._panels.length);
        
        var panels = this._panels;
        panels.push(this.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Panel ' + panels.length,
            height: 50,
            width: '100%'
        }));
    },
    
    tbar: [{
        xtype : 'button',
        text: 'add',
        handler: 'addPanel'
    }]

});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that move `this._panels = [];` inside `initComponent` to make it instance specific.

Comment: yeah I agree with your answer I just did the same in constructor ... cause I'm used to initilize classes in contructors :D

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer for this is prototypal inheritance (see [this MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) article).  Basically your non-primitives will carry over to new instances because they exist on your prototype class, and because they're non-primitives, it's the same exact reference that's used.  To fix this, I would recommend wrapping your `_panels` variable in the [config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config) block, like below, and encourage you to use the appropriate set/get methods, instead of accessing it directly:

```
config: {
    _panels : []
}
```

Comment: I moved them to constructor as I want to have these properties "private"

Comment: You could still use the config approach but mark it as `private` with a comment if it's a concern, but what you did is another totally acceptable approach to this.

Comment: you can use onDestroy: function() {
      this._panels.length = 0
    },. It will empty the array.

Comment: @Ovais - you don't want to do that, because the `_panels` reference is being shared with other instances of the class (because, as incutonez said, it's coming from the prototype). The right solution is to make it _not_ be shared.

Comment: I ended fixing my application to work like this 
[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38s9). I moved properties to constructor. ` constructor: function() {
      Ext.apply(this, {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,

            layout: 'vbox',

            _panels : [],

      });
      this.callParent(arguments);
    },`

Answer (score 0):

A *less than correct answer* if the prototype behavior in the previous answer is "A feature/intentional bad code/ legacy code with unintended consequences"

Manually **overwrite** the prototype Value, following instantiation of the panel

[image: manually overwrite _.panels]

Comment: Note, the "Less than correct answer" that references points made in previous answer.

If you are in a legacy system, where the bad behavior was there before, it can be problematic to correct. Also accept the previous answer, as it answers the question.